# Backslash vs. Forward slash in Java and Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I've been doing some pretty typical coding projects for a CS class at school, and one or two of them involve reading files. I'm curious why the filepaths outputted by my Windows 7 machine and read by my Java IDE Eclipse use different facing slashes. For example `C:\Users\jhobbie\Desktop\eclipse` gives an error "invalid escape sequence" and I have to go in and switch all the slashes to `C:/Users/jhobbie/Desktop/eclipse`. I understand what the error message means, I'm just wondering why Windows would output (and I assume use?) different direction slashes than Java. Is there an alternate way of reading file names other than strings that allows this formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get the relation between your text and your header.

Comment: the backslash \ is a reserved caracter in java. That's why it gives an error when you use it inadequately. If you want to use a backslash in a string you have to had another backslash \\. So the string for that extension using backslash would be: "C:\\Users\\jhobbie\\Desktop\\eclipse"

Comment: Not really. I know that I should use forward slash, I'm just unclear why Windows gives me the address in a different way

Comment: Is this a programming question? In any case, a better discussion is available here: http://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses backslah as separator. The reason is historical:  MSDOS 1.0 did use backslash and all other msdos and windows version use it for backwards compatibility. Although most Microsoft products should theoretically also accept slash.